# Multiple Row Inserion via subQuery

Tags: mysql, subquery, bulkinsert, multiple-records

i am trying to insert multiple rows using a subquery but it gives and error **"SubQuery Returns more than 1 rows"**

scenario is that i want to add comment against every test of a subdepartment, i am getting all test id's via subquery but i not being able to iterate over id's and insert comment against each test. Here is my SQL Query

```
INSERT INTO dc_tp_comment  (labid,branchid,Comment,testid,lastupdated,enteredby)
Values('abcd',101,'comment here',(select T.testid
from dc_tp_test T
Inner Join dc_tp_subdepartments S
on T.subdepartmentid = S.subdepartmentid
Where S.subdepartmentid = 13),sysdate(),1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use subselect in just one column, use them for whole row:

```
INSERT INTO dc_tp_comment  (labid,branchid,Comment,testid,lastupdated,enteredby)
select 'abcd',101,'comment here', T.testid, sysdate() , 1
from dc_tp_test T Inner Join dc_tp_subdepartments S
on T.subdepartmentid = S.subdepartmentid
Where S.subdepartmentid = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Use select insted of values if you want to insert multiple rows...

Syntax would be like:

```
INSERT INTO dc_tp_comment  (labid,branchid,Comment,testid,lastupdated,enteredby)
select 'abcd',101,'comment here',(select T.testid
from dc_tp_test T
Inner Join dc_tp_subdepartments S
on T.subdepartmentid = S.subdepartmentid
Where S.subdepartmentid = 13),sysdate(),1
```

Comment: returns same error "SubQuery Returns more than 1 rows"